# From gnome-screenshot command line, how do you predefine the area?

Tags: command-line, gnome, screenshot

So gnome-screenshot has the following options:

```
tim@Hairy14:~$ gnome-screenshot --help
Usage:
  gnome-screenshot [OPTION…] Take a picture of the screen

Help Options:
  -h, --help                     Show help options
  --help-all                     Show all help options
  --help-gtk                     Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  -c, --clipboard                Send the grab directly to the clipboard
  -w, --window                   Grab a window instead of the entire screen
  -a, --area                     Grab an area of the screen instead of the entire screen
  -b, --include-border           Include the window border with the screenshot
  -B, --remove-border            Remove the window border from the screenshot
  -p, --include-pointer          Include the pointer with the screenshot
  -d, --delay=seconds            Take screenshot after specified delay [in seconds]
  -e, --border-effect=effect     Effect to add to the border (shadow, border, vintage or none)
  -i, --interactive              Interactively set options
  -f, --file=filename            Save screenshot directly to this file
  --version                      Print version information and exit
  --display=DISPLAY              X display to use
```

The one I'm interested in is `-a`.

If it run it, the following happens, I can click and drag anywhere on the screen and it saves an image, of the are I chose.

I have the short cut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> set up for this.

But what I want is a predefined area, somehting allong the lines of this:

```
gnome-screenshot -a 400x500+100x100
```

(i.e. 400 down, 500 in and 100x100 area).

Is this possible, and is there a command to do this?

NB: I could use the image cropping tool `convert -crop` like this:

```
convert -crop 100x100+50+50 Pictures/Screenshot.png Pictures/Screenshot-cropped.png
```

but I would like it if it was built in, as cropping a full print screen makes it blurry...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like there isn't such an option but you can control your mouse from command line using `xdotool`, so you can try to play with it:

```
(gnome-screenshot -a &); sleep 0.1 && xdotool mousemove 100 100 mousedown 1 mousemove 500 500 mouseup 1
```

I use `(cmd &)` syntax to have command running in background (using just && here won't work because `gnome-screenshot` waits for input) and make small delay (try to experiment with values of sleep) to be sure that mouse won't be moving before it's ready. Then I use `mousemove x y`, `mousedown 1` and `mouseup 1` commands to simulate grabbing an area.

You should also check out more suited tool for getting screenshots which is `import` from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/):

```
import -window root ~/Pictures/img.png -crop 100x100+1100+1100
```